# Проверка соседних ячеек массива в игре крестики-нолики

Tags: java, массивы

Задание: необходимо реализовать ИИ при игре в крестики-нолики на джаве. Самый первый шаг рандомный выбор ячейки и проверка соседних ячеек на, скажем, нолики. реализовал в лоб:

```
if (map[i+1][j] == DOT_O ||
    map[i+1][j+1] == DOT_O ||
    map[i+1][j-1] == DOT_O ||
    map[i][j+1] == DOT_O ||
    map[i][j-1] == DOT_O ||
    map[i-1][j] == DOT_O ||
    map[i-1][j+1] == DOT_O ||
    map[i-1][j-1] == DOT_O
)  {
    x = i;
    y = j;
}
```

но тут сразу ошибка, т.к. при обращении к ячейке типа i+1 можно выйти за край массива. Теперь сам завис не пойму как подойти к проблеме. Хелп, пожалуйста.

Comment: Обычно в подобных играх не проверяют после каждого хода ВСЕ выигрышные варианты, а только что касается последнего хода. Конечно, если классические Х-0 (3х3), то ничего страшного, но если вы захотите сделать поле 100500х100500, тогда логичнее проверить только вертикаль-горизонталь-диагонали только от последнего хода.

Comment: столкнулся с аналогичной задачей, тоже добавил проверку " и " на (i+1 < SIZE), но не вышло - вылетает ошибка > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 3 пока непонятно, как избавиться от этого -1. я уж и проверки добавил, что (i - 1) >= 0 && (j - 1) >= 0, но не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean checkNearCell(int row, int col, int val) {
  int startRow = Math.max(row - 1, 0);
  int stopRow = Math.min(row + 1, map.length - 1);
  for (int i = startRow; i <= stopRow; i++) {
    int startCol = Math.max(col - 1, 0);
    int stopCol = Math.min(col + 1, map[i].length - 1);
    for (int j = startCol; j <= stopCol; j++) {
      if (map[i][j] == val && !(i == row && j == col))
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

if (checkNearCell(i, j, DOT_O) {
  x = i;
  y = j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

решил всё таки в лоб, просто перед каждой проверкой " или " добавил проверку " и " на (i+1 < SIZE), т.е. что бы не проверял ячейку с координатой за пределами массива. спасибо.